# Azure Redis cache not expired properly

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

I am using Azure Redis Cache with 250MB storage, and am storing list of objects with expire time.When i save more list of objects with different key means expire time not working properly. If there is no data means its working fine, refreshing in every 10 mins. But in work load time its not working properly.

How to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A 250 MB redis cache is hosted on Extra Small (A0) virtual machines, which is hosted using shared cores, has limited bandwidth and is as such not recommended for production workloads. You could check your cache performance counters for CPU and Bandwidth to see if you might be hitting such limits.